# Azure data factory to split a CSV file into multiple CSV files?

Tags: azure, csv, lookup, azure-data-factory

I have a file in Azure blob container as below,

```
[Header 1]
123,abc,456,def,..
[Header 2]
789,XYZ, 101,PQR,..
567,DEF,675,GEF,..
```

I am expecting Azure data factory to convert it into multiple CSV files in blob container as below,

```
CSV1 file:
    123,abc,456,def,..
CSV2 file:
    789,XYZ, 101,PQR,..
    567,DEF,675,GEF,..
```

The number of headers is known and always constant. But the number of rows under each header can vary.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

create a dataflow,add two source,create select and delete column you don't need,finally output to a single file.

screenshot of dataflow:
[image]

setting of sink:
[image]

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks! But the Select will allow selecting columns from the CSV. I need to select rows based on the header.